# Error with T::iterator, where template parameter T might be vector<int> or list<int>

Tags: c++, templates, stl, repr

I'm trying to write a function to print a representation of common STL containers (vector, list, etc..). I gave the function a template parameter T which, for example, might represent vector. I'm having problems getting an iterator of type T.

```
vector<int> v(10, 0);
repr< vector<int> >(v);
```

...

```
template <typename T>
void repr(const T & v)
{
    cout << "[";
    if (!v.empty())
    {
        cout << ' ';
        T::iterator i;
        for (i = v.begin(); 
             i != v.end()-1;
             ++i)
        {
            cout << *i << ", ";
        }
        cout << *(++i) << ' ';
    }
    cout << "]\n";
}
```

...

```
brett@brett-laptop:~/Desktop/stl$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘void repr(const T&)’:
main.cpp:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
main.cpp:14: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: In function ‘void repr(const T&) [with T = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]’:
main.cpp:33:   instantiated from here
main.cpp:13: error: dependent-name ‘T::iterator’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
main.cpp:13: note: say ‘typename T::iterator’ if a type is meant
```

I tried 'typename T::iterator' as the compiler suggested, but only got a more cryptic error.

Edit: Thanks for the help guys! Here's a working version for anyone who wants to use this function:

```
template <typename T>
void repr(const T & v)
{
    cout << "[";
    if (!v.empty())
    {
        cout << ' ';
        typename T::const_iterator i;
        for (i = v.begin(); 
             i != v.end();
             ++i)
        {
            if (i != v.begin())
            {
                cout << ", ";
            }
            cout << *i;
        }
        cout << ' ';
    }
    cout << "]\n";
}
```

Comment: How about posting the "more cryptic" error message too?

Comment: btw, you might want to replace v.end()-1 with something else that non-RandomAccess-iterators support as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need `typename` to tell the compiler that `::iterator` is supposed to be a type. The compiler doesn't know that it's a type because it doesn't know what T is until you instantiate the template. It could also refer to some static data member, for example. That's your first error.

Your second error is that `v` is a reference-to-**const**. So, instead of `::iterator` you have to use `::const_iterator`. You can't ask a constant container for a non-const iterator.

Comment: Not so much that the compiler doesn't know what `::iterator` is, but the standard requires it to interpret it as a non-type, as it is nicely put in the error message: "dependent-name ‘`T::iterator`’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type"

Comment: @visitor: With a correct two-phase implementation (read "not MSVC") the compiler can't know what `iterator` is in the first pass because the template parameters are not set yet. See e.g. item 6 and 7 [here](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation).

Answer (score 4):

Change `T::iterator i;` to `typename T::const_iterator i;` because `::iterator` is of type `T` and `v` is a `const &`.

Before a qualified dependent type, you need `typename`.
Without `typename`, there is a C++ parsing rule that says that qualified dependent names should be parsed as `non-types` even if it leads to a syntax error.

`typename` states that the name that follows should be treated as a type. Otherwise, names are interpreted to refer to non-types.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

Typename is mandatory before a qualified-dependent name which refers to a type, unless that name is naming a base class, or in an initialization list. Typename is optional before a qualified (but non-dependent name) is used within a template, except again when naming a base class or in an initialization list.