# Why do I get "Expected ;" error and "Variable not declared in scope" error?

Tags: c++

i have following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<class  Container>
void print(const Container &c)
{

   Container::const_iterator itr;
   for (itr=c.begin();itr!=c.end();itr++){
      cout<<*itr<< '\n';
}

}

int main(){

   set<string,greater<string>>s;
   s.insert("georgia");
   s.insert("saqartvelo");
   print(s);
   return 0;

}
```

but errors are

```
reverse.cpp: In function ‘void print(const Container&)’:
reverse.cpp:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘itr’
reverse.cpp:10: error: ‘itr’ was not declared in this scope
reverse.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
reverse.cpp:17: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
reverse.cpp:17: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list
```

What might cause this and how do I solve it?

Comment: legitimate question, but tersely asked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with T::iterator, where template parameter T might be vector<int> or list<int>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735022/error-with-titerator-where-template-parameter-t-might-be-vectorint-or-listi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `typename Container::const_iterator` instead of `Container::const_iterator`.

At the point the compiler is reading your code, it doesn't know that `Container` has such a type (it is a so-called *dependent* name).

Answer (score 5):

Alexandre is right about the first two errors. The last two are due to an annoying syntax limitation of C++: you need to have a space in between the two closing brackets in the template expression:

```
set<string,greater<string> > s;
```

Otherwise, C++ interprets it as the right shift `>>` operator.

Comment: ah there were other errors ? ;) I didn't read past the dependant lookup actually...