# When should I use typename in a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735022/error-with-titerator-where-template-parameter-t-might-be-vectorint-or-list), `typename` should be added to tell compiler that `iterator` is a type (Is it correct?), e.g.

```
template <typename T>
void print(vector<T> &v) {
  for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}
```

Two questions:

1. Under what circumstances should a `typename` be added? Can someone give me another example?
2. Can `auto` in C++11 replace all these `typename xxx` cases?

Comment: This is one of the canonical examples of `auto` being useful.

Comment: 1) See the link above. 2) Yes, this is one of the great benefits of `auto`, it replaces many of these annoying things.

Comment: Of course if you want the proper type from `auto`, you'll need `cbegin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you are referring to a typename whose exact meaning depends on a template parameter.
2. Not all, but many. `auto` has to be able to infer/deduce the type. In something like this:

   ```
   typename T:foo_t var;
   ```

for example, it can't.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer. I will take time to read the link above - quite a long post :)

Comment: It's basically a hint to help the parser.